# Delphi XE5 not showing line that raised exception

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5

While testing my delphi application, some Exceptions are raised but the debugger is not showing where (like it used to). Is there a setting which is causing this?

EDIT: When an exception occurs, a message appears alerting me to the fact that an error has occurred and what type of exception it is. Normally, I would be able to click 'break' and it would show me at which line the error had occurred, but when I click break, this doesn't happen.

Comment: What errors are occuring?  How do you know there are errors?  What do they look like?  Do they have messages?  Does your program stop running?  We cannot see your screen.  Describe the problem in more detail.

Comment: @J... have updated with more details

Comment: You probably mean, how to break on exceptions?

Comment: @ToonKrijthe YES Exactly what I mean!

Comment: Do you know which exception is ignored?

Comment: Another idea, do you have all your debug information on? If you don't have this, you won't get there.

Comment: `...when I click break, this doesn't happen` - what *does* happen?  Does the application just keep running?  Does it break to CPU view?

Comment: The view changes to the code view but doesn't show where the exception occured and the application continues to run.

Comment: @ToonKrijthe I don't know :/ The problem isn't that exceptions aren't appearing. It's the fact that it won't break to the line that is causing the exception

Comment: Make sure you're using the "run" button (has picture of ladybug) and not the "run without debugging" button (just a green arrow), on the Delphi toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

It might help if you post a screen shot of what you actually do see before and after clicking Break.

And you haven't really answered the very first comment on your question: "What errors are occurring?" The point is if it's specific exceptions that aren't showing the code - they may be occurring in an external DLL.

As a first step check if Delphi will show the exception in the most simple case:

- Drop a button on your form.
- Write an OnClick handler with the following code: `raise Exception.Create('This is a test');`
- **NOTE** Make sure you try this in both your existing app, and in a brand new stand-alone app.

If Delphi doesn't show you that exception in the simple app, I'd be very surprised, and some more serious digging will be required.

If it is shown in the simple app, but not in yours, then there's some specific problem in your  project:

- Ensure you aren't disabling debug info `{$D-}` or `{$DEBUGINFO OFF}` somewhere in your project.
- You might have exception hooking code in your project that is somehow interfering. Try disabling exception loggers and similar tools to narrow down the problem. (*Don't forget to re-enable the appropriate tools once the issue is resolved*.)
- Verify that your search and browsing paths are correctly configured to find the source code in order to show you the error.

If the simple exception is shown in both apps, then we'll probably need to know exactly what exceptions aren't showing to help further. However, here are a few more pointers (^s):

- Go to Tools | Options. Under Debugger Options, look for Native OS Exceptions. Verify you haven't changed any of these settings.
- When the exception occurs, open your Thread Viewer, and check if the the exception was raised on the main thread or another thread.
- Also open your Call-stack Viewer, and verify you actually do have a call-stack.
- Then check if Delphi will show the code for any of the call-stack lines.

> **NOTE** There is still the possibility that Delphi is simply unable to find the source unit depending on *where* the exception is raised. However, Delphi is supposed to prompt you and ask where it can load the file from in such situations. (*It definitely worked in older versions of Delphi*.)
>   But I wouldn't rule it out because a buggy plugin might well be suppressing the prompt.

Answer (score -1):

You can control the reaction of the debugger on exceptions from within the options.

- Go to Tools\Options.
- Click on the Debugger Options, then on language exceptions.

You probably have unchecked "Notify on language exceptions".

Else you can enable as much as possible.

Be sure to enable all debug information in your project:

- Debug information
- Symbol reference info

And try without optimizing.

Comment: Another possibillity is that he accidentally added the base class `Exception` or some other class to the list of ignored exceptions.

Comment: @GünthertheBeautiful how do I go about fixing that?

Comment: @GünthertheBeautiful the ignored exceptions are:
VCL EAbort Exceptions,
Indy Silent Exceptions,
Microsoft DAO Exceptions,
System.Threading.SynchronizationLockException,
System.threading.ThreadAbortException

Comment: @Seryth As far as I can see, that's the way it should be. So you're not ignoring all exceptions. What kind of exception are you trying to catch?

Comment: EConvertError
and
Row cannot be located for updating